# How to delete Google task from Google Task queue programmatically using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, task-queue

How to delete a task from Google Task queue programmatically using **Node.js**?

[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/taskqueue/push/deleting-tasks-and-queues?authuser=1) doesn't tell us anything about it in Node.js

[Task Queue Link](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudtasks/queue/us-central1/%7Bqueue-name%7D/tasks?authuser=1&project=%7Bproject-name%7D)

Comment: Your first link talks about App Engine, but your second link refers to Cloud Tasks.  These are different products and don't have the same API.  I suggest editing the question to add some more context about what you're actually trying to do, showing any code that you have so far.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/tasks/latest/v2.CloudTasksClient.html#deleteTask) and [this one](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2beta3/projects.locations.queues.tasks/delete?hl=es-419) that mention how to delete the task. Only please keep in mind that a task **cannot be deleted if it has executed successfully or permanently failed.**

This is the code that the Google's documentation mentions :

```html
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const cloudtasks = google.cloudtasks('v2beta3');

async function main () {
  const authClient = await authorize();
  const request = {
    // Required. The task name. For example:
    // `projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION_ID/queues/QUEUE_ID/tasks/TASK_ID`
    name: 'projects/my-project/locations/my-location/queues/my-queue/tasks/my-task',  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    auth: authClient,
  };

  try {
    await cloudtasks.projects.locations.queues.tasks.delete(request);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
main();

async function authorize() {
  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
  });
  return await auth.getClient();
}
```

I really hope that this information helps you :)